# How to join on a table where the column should not exist or the queried value should be NOT BETWEEN the dates?

Tags: mysql, join

I know my title isn't the best.
What I try to accomplish is this:

I have 4 tables:

- Parking_Spots
- Addresses
- Availability
- Bookings

My query takes 3 arguments:

- zipcode
- from ( desired start date(time) )
- to( desired end date(time) )

first we filter parkingspots

```
INNER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Addresses`
    ON (
      `deb93093_api`.`Parking_Spots`.`address` = `Addresses`.`uuid`
    )
```

===

```
WHERE (`Addresses`.`zipCode` = '4651AA')
```

Then the available parkingspots

```
INNER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Availability`
    ON (
      `Availability`.`parkingSpot` = `Parking_Spots`.`uuid`
    )
```

===

```
AND (
     '2016-12-31' BETWEEN `Availability`.`fromDate` AND `Availability`.`toDate`
  )
AND (
    '2016-12-31' BETWEEN `Availability`.`fromDate` AND `Availability`.`toDate`
  )
```

But here is the problem:

I need to get the parkingspots that are not already booked in bookings for the desired times

```
-- AND (
 --   '2016-12-31' NOT BETWEEN `Bookings`.`from` AND `Availability`.`to`
 -- )

 -- AND (
 --   '2016-12-31' NOT BETWEEN `Bookings`.`from` AND `Availability`.`to`
 -- )
```

But an inner join would just try to show the parking spots that have records for them. They should however show the ones without bookings as well. Is there a type of join I can use? I would like to select the avaiable parkingspots, which is

available = parkingspots_with_right_zipcode - only that are available - the ones that are set to available by the owner, but already booked

Full query up to this point:

```
SELECT
  `Parking_Spots`.*
FROM
  `deb93093_api`.`Parking_Spots`

  INNER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Addresses`
    ON (
      `deb93093_api`.`Parking_Spots`.`address` = `Addresses`.`uuid`
    )
  INNER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Availability`
    ON (
      `Availability`.`parkingSpot` = `Parking_Spots`.`uuid`
    )

  OUTER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Bookings`
   ON (
     `Bookings`.`parkingSpot` = `Parking_Spots`.`uuid`
   )



 WHERE (`Addresses`.`zipCode` = '4651AA')
  AND (
     '2016-12-31' BETWEEN `Availability`.`fromDate` AND `Availability`.`toDate`
  )
  AND (
    '2016-12-31' BETWEEN `Availability`.`fromDate` AND `Availability`.`toDate`
  )

 -- AND (
 --   '2016-12-31' NOT BETWEEN `Bookings`.`from` AND `Availability`.`to`
 -- )

 -- AND (
 --   '2016-12-31' NOT BETWEEN `Bookings`.`from` AND `Availability`.`to`
 -- )
```

[image]

from and to are bookings, so I want to filter our those who are already booked for the desired time. However if there are no records for that parkingspot in bookings, it should still show the parkingspot as it is NOT booked (so available)

PSEUDE CODE TO FURTHER CLARIFY

```
 (
AND (
WHERE $desired_from NOT BETWEEN Bookings`.`from` AND `Bookings`.`to` )

  AND (
    $desired_to NOT BETWEEN `Bookings`.`from` AND `Bookings`.`to`
  )
OR
WHERE [there is no record in Bookings]
```

Comment: `NOT BETWEEN` is a thing

Comment: @CptMisery thanks cap obvious I already even got it in comment in my Question. However it also needs to find records from `parking_spots` where there are no records for it in `bookings`

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

In situation like that you can use `LEFT JOIN` with additional conditions in the join `ON` clause and then filter only rows where no joining records where found:

```
SELECT
  `Parking_Spots`.*
FROM
  `deb93093_api`.`Parking_Spots`

  INNER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Addresses`
    ON (
      `deb93093_api`.`Parking_Spots`.`address` = `Addresses`.`uuid`
    )
  INNER JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Availability`
    ON (
      `Availability`.`parkingSpot` = `Parking_Spots`.`uuid`
    )

  LEFT JOIN `deb93093_api`.`Bookings`
   ON (
     `Bookings`.`parkingSpot` = `Parking_Spots`.`uuid`
   ) 
   AND (
     '2016-12-31' BETWEEN `Bookings`.`from` AND `Bookings`.`to`
   )

 WHERE (`Addresses`.`zipCode` = '4651AA')
  AND (
     '2016-12-31' BETWEEN `Availability`.`fromDate` AND `Availability`.`toDate`
  )
  AND `Bookings`.`uuid` IS NULL -- THIS MEANS THE SPOT IS NOT BOOKED
```

Comment: I will add bookings table structure to the question, because I think that will not work

Comment: So if there are no `booking`-records at all, it should show all `parkingspots` that are available in `Availability` as there are no spots in use already.

Comment: @Thomas shouldn't then my query work? Left join works so that all the records from the first joining table are present in the result, they will just have NULL's in fields corresponding to the second table (which is what the where condition is checking).

Comment: What about the parkingspots that are booked, but are free at the desired timespan?

Comment: @Thomas Again, could you be more specific why you think this case will be handled incorrectly?

Comment: there is not even a where clause for the specification, how can it work? I also tried it, but no results at all